# Within a paragraph that is underlined how to exclude a series of words from being underlined (text-decoration none)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

In Zurb Foundation 4 I want to underline all below text except "Shipping International" for which I've tried various css to set as text decoration "none" but I can't seem to figure out what the correct CSS to resolve this is:

```
<div class="row">
```

```
 <p class="buy-button"><a href="#" class="medium button buy">Add to cart</a></p><br>
 <p class="small-font"><a href="#">usually leaves our warehouse in 1 business day.</a><br>
 <a href="#">Available for Pick Up NYC</a> <br>
 <span class="overview">Shipping: International</span> <a href="#">(See Terms &amp Conditions)</a> </p>
    </div>
```

I did a span with a class but it's not working.

The HTML and CSS can be seen in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/setbon/f8p62/

Any help to resolve is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `text-decoration:underline;` from your `.small-font` styling.

Here's the full CSS:

```
.medium.button.buy {
  background-color: green;
  /*  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;*/
  padding-left: 4em;
  padding-right: 4em;
}

.small-font {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.panel p.buy-button {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}
```

And the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/3pghs/).